# How is leisure/tourism calculated for nearby buildings?

Tags: cities-skylines

I recently realized I need more leisure/tourism buildings in my city. I started plopping down Japanese Gardens and Skateparks, happily seeing my buildings turn from red to white on the map. But sometimes, putting down a new park would do nothing for buildings literally right by the park.

So my question: how is the leisure/tourism boost calculated for nearby buildings?

It appears to be related to walking distance/accessibility, and possibly is greatly diminished across 4- or 6-lane roads, but I can’t figure out the specifics.

If it helps, I’m playing the vanilla Nintendo Switch version.